# Update multiple values in a table in a single query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table say 'Table1' as shown below

```
  Table1
  ---------------
  Name  | Value
  ----------------
  name1 | val1

  name2 | val2

  name3 | val3

  name4 | val4
```

here I need to update 'Values' field based on 'Name'

I have used below stored procedure to do this,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateDetails] 
(
    @name1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @name2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @name3 NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @name4 NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Table1 SET Value = @name1 WHERE Name = 'name1';
    UPDATE Table1 SET Value = @name2 WHERE Name = 'name2';
    UPDATE Table1 SET Value = @name3 WHERE Name = 'name3';
    UPDATE Table1 SET Value = @name4 WHERE Name = 'name4';
END
```

what would be the best way to update this table?

Comment: Your sp looks like good. You have 4 param right?

Comment: @Hebele , In my actual senario, there are 9 parameters, and I need to update all these fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET Value = CASE Name WHEN 'name1' THEN @name1
                      WHEN 'name2' THEN @name2
                      WHEN 'name3' THEN @name3
                      WHEN 'name4' THEN @name4                    
            END
WHERE Name in ('name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4');
```

Comment: I think the where clause is not required.

Comment: @Jobin If you don's where clause, Value column will be set to NULL for all other records with name other than name1, name2, name3 or name4.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CASE` statement for this. I recommend you add an ELSE statement at the bottom. The bottom part will filter so you only update rows that you are searching for.

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Value = 
                     CASE WHEN Name = 'name1' THEN @name1 
                          WHEN Name = 'name2' THEN @name2 
                          WHEN Name = 'name3' THEN @name3 
                          WHEN Name = 'name4' THEN @name4 
                          ELSE Value
                     END
 WHERE Name in ('name1','name2','name3','name4')
```

Comment: WHERE condition is incorrect. It should check Name in name1, name2, etc..

Comment: @Swapnil Corrected, thanks! Even though we had the same answer, looks like yours was picked by Jobin.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explicitly said so, but usually when you do this, you don't know at coding time how many rows will be in your table, nor how many of them you want to update at any given moment. The quickest way to deal with this is to put the loop in the C#. You'll need two parameters, @name and @value, which you'll create outside the loop, then you just change their values for each iteration of the loop. So your code will look like...

```
Dictionary<string, string> myUpdates = new Dictionary<string, string>();
myUpdates.Add("name1", "value1");
myUpdates.Add("name2", "value2");
myUpdates.Add("name3", "value3");
myUpdates.Add("name4", "value4");

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Table1 set value = @value where name = @name", connection);
    var nameParam = new SqlParameter("name", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    var valueParam = new SqlParameter("value", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    command.Parameters.Add(nameParam);
    command.Parameters.Add(valueParam);
    connection.Open();
    foreach (var item in myUpdates)
    {
        try
        {
            nameParam.Value = item.Key;
            valueParam.Value = item.Value;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

"name" and "value" are worryingly abstract names for DB columns. In general, your DB column names should be more closely tied to the "real world". They're probably just examples ?

Answer (score -1):

You can rather use a dynamic sql query. Something like below.
I would take like pass value1, name1 and iterate on procedure call.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateDetails] 
    (
    @l_value NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @l_name NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = 'UPDATE Table1 SET Value = [' + @l_value + '] WHERE Name =['+ @l_name + '] '

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql

    END
```